# Convergence of a function of a normal random variable to $Norm(0,1)$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

We are given the following:

\begin{equation}\frac{X_n-\mu}{\sigma_n^2}\overset{D}{\rightarrow} Norm(0,1),\end{equation}

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sigma_n^2=0$,

$f(x)$ is differentiable and $f'(\mu)\neq0$.

Prove:

\begin{equation}\frac{f(X_n)-f(\mu)}{[f'(\mu)]^2\sigma_n^2}
\overset{D}{\rightarrow} Norm(0,1)
\end{equation}

How? Law of large numbers?

Answer (score 1):

The thing you wrote is a so called Delta-method. I think you can find the answer by simple googling now, but here are some hints: use the mean-value theorem and Slutsky’s Lemma.

Comment: I am still lost. I need some help getting the ball rolling.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Proof_in_the_univariate_case